# "what is to come" in a novel when writing in past tense

Tags: past-tense, idiomatic-language, auxiliary-verbs

Context: I'm editing a novel. The novel is written in past tense.
I'm concerned about the following passage:

> With a cough he faced the clan elders and said, “Everyone, the hour is late. For tomorrow’s ceremony, you should all rest well tonight.”
>   At his words, the elders looked at each other with a hint of caution in their eyes. The clan head’s words meant well, but everyone understood what he was talking about. Each year, when vying for these young geniuses, the elders would fight among themselves to the point of reddened ears and bleeding heads. They should stay well rested and replenish themselves for what is to come.

The thing I'm concerned about is `should` and `what is to come`.

I'm not sure if the current usage of `should` is correct when the novel is written in past tense. It sounds okayish, but I have a faint suspicion that the construction may be different in past tense.

Regarding `what is to come`, it's equivalent to `tomorrow` in this case, and I'm not sure if it's `what is to come` or `what was to come` considering the novel is written in past tense.

Comment: Agreed; "should" and "is to come" are in the wrong tense. Try "needed to" and "was to come"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Juhasz's comment, `should` should be changed to `needed to` and `is to come` should be changed to `was to come`.